# How to remove computer from Domain (C# Code) and then add to workgroup?

Tags: c#, windows, dns, workgroup

My requirement is to `join` a computer to a `Workgroup`. It works well in the normal scenario. But if computer is already part of a domain, then my code doesn't work.

I assume that at first computer needs to be removed from Domain and then added to Workgroup. Does anybody know how can computer be removed from Domain?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that if the computer is part of a domain the user running your software may not have the rights to remove it from that domain. That is quite likely to be a domain admin privileged action. If so then your software isn't going to be able to do it either!

I'm not sure what it is about your software that won't work in a domain, but it might be worthwhile focusing on that instead.

Comment: +1 for the 2nd para. You don't need to be a domain admin to remove a computer from a domain, just need to have admin rights on the machine (I've had to do this more times than I care to remember)

Comment: Yes, you're right about a local admin being able to do that. Quite often its the case that users of domain bound machines aren't local admin. Depends how much grief they give their domain administrator I guess!

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer but too long for comment: most management samples are in VBscript so when searching expect most results to require conversion...

Links that together should let you write removal code:

- [Remove a Computer From a Domain (ADSI/VB Script)](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=5151)
- [ADSI Objects of WinNT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa772211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  and linked [IADsContainer::Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa705988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [How to access ADSI objects in Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315716)

Code chunks:

```
// VBScript
Set objDC = getobject("WinNT://" & strDomain )
objDC.Delete( "Computer", strComputer
```

C# access to ADSI object:

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry();
de.Path = "WinNT://YOURDOMAIN";
```